# How to copy column values and column names into unique ID value and maintain cell information in r?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a wide format data frame that I am looking to make long by shortening columns, but cannot figure out how to get pivot_longer() and paste() to work together properly.

Here is an example dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(Site_Number  = c(1, 1, 1, 2),
                 Subsite_Number = c(1, 2, 3, 1),
                  C1 = c("Red", "Blue", "Green", "Red"),
                  C2 = c("Red", "Red", "Red", "Red"),
                  C3 = c("Blue", "Green", "NA", "Blue"),
                  C4 = c("Red", "NA", "NA", "NA"))
```

Which looks like:

```
  Site_Number Subsite_Number    C1  C2    C3  C4
           1              1   Red Red  Blue Red
           1              2  Blue Red Green  NA
           1              3 Green Red    NA  NA
           2              1   Red Red  Blue  NA
```

I want to create a unique ID from the Site_Number, Subsite_Number, and 'C' value (column name), putting the dataframe into long format, but maintaining values from the C columns. The trick is that there are NAs in some 'C' columns, which do not need to be translated into the new dataset. Here is the output I am hoping for:

```
     ID  Color
 S1T1C1   Red
 S1T1C2   Red
 S1T1C3  Blue
 S1T1C4   Red
 S1T2C1  Blue
 S1T2C2   Red
 S1T2C3 Green
 S1T3C1 Green
 S1T3C2   Red
 S2T1C1   Red
 S2T1C2   Red
 S2T1C3  Blue
```

S = Site_Number, T = Subsite_Number, C comes from column names of C1:4 to create ID number.

Any ideas on how to manipulate this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df |>
  mutate(ID = paste0("S", Site_Number, "T", Subsite_Number)) |>
  select(-Site_Number, -Subsite_Number) |>
  pivot_longer(-ID) |>
  filter(value != "NA" & !is.na(value)) |>
  mutate(ID = paste0(ID, name))
# # A tibble: 12 × 3
#    ID     name  value
#    <chr>  <chr> <chr>
#  1 S1T1C1 C1    Red  
#  2 S1T1C2 C2    Red  
#  3 S1T1C3 C3    Blue 
#  4 S1T1C4 C4    Red  
#  5 S1T2C1 C1    Blue 
#  6 S1T2C2 C2    Red  
#  7 S1T2C3 C3    Green
#  8 S1T3C1 C1    Green
#  9 S1T3C2 C2    Red  
# 10 S2T1C1 C1    Red  
# 11 S2T1C2 C2    Red  
# 12 S2T1C3 C3    Blue
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
df %>%
  mutate(ID = str_c('S', Site_Number, 'T', Subsite_Number), .keep='unused')%>%
  mutate(across(-ID, ~na_if(.x, 'NA'))) %>% # type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
  pivot_longer(C1:C4, values_to = 'Color', values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  unite(ID, ID, name, sep = '')

   ID     Color
   <chr>  <chr>
 1 S1T1C1 Red  
 2 S1T1C2 Red  
 3 S1T1C3 Blue 
 4 S1T1C4 Red  
 5 S1T2C1 Blue 
 6 S1T2C2 Red  
 7 S1T2C3 Green
 8 S1T3C1 Green
 9 S1T3C2 Red  
10 S2T1C1 Red  
11 S2T1C2 Red  
12 S2T1C3 Blue
```